# My Visual Studio 2019 stopped connecting Azure Devops repos. It was working even few days back

Tags: git, azure-devops, visual-studio-2019

If I try to clone directly from VS, it shows the following error.

"Unable to start process. Timeout waiting for child process to open named pipes."

Comment: My guess would be an issue with a virus scanner or enterprise allowlist tool. What happens when you call `git clone` from the mingit that ships with visual studio?

Comment: Your VS requires to reauthenticate.  In VS Studio, in the top right corner area, click on your initials circle icon, then go to Accounts Settings... OR go to File -> Account Settings. Under the section "All Accounts" it will show a problem with your Azure DevOps authentication.  Reauthenticate to fix it and then you will be good to go.

Comment: This was not the case. Everything looks good in Accounts Settings. I opened VS as Administrator. That resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I opened Visual Studio as Administrator. That resolved the issue.